# Is insert multiple rows using MySQL insert values syntax executed in serializable?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
create table tmp
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(20)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

when i use MySQL insert values syntax insert multiple rows in one statement.

```
insert into tmp(name) values('tom'), ('cat'), ('rat');
```

is that inserted row by row in serializable?

Comment: What do you mean by "in serializable"?

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ney9DiVw)

Comment: I sense that your motivation for this question is something different. I would guess that you're wondering if the auto-increment is bound to use consecutive values, or if a concurrent insert could steal some of the id values. The answer to that depends on some innodb configuration options, but the default configuration will ensure that the multi-row insert uses consecutive values. Read the manual page for more details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html